# Does Xcode have a MSVS "Edit and Continue" equivalent?

Tags: visual-studio, xcode, xcode4

I found this feature very useful and was wondering if Xcode (any version) had something similar.

Comment: See: [Hot Code Swapping in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10196155/1402846).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hot Code Swapping in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196155/hot-code-swapping-in-xcode)

Answer (score 3):

It used to have a feature called "Fix and Continue" which was probably equivalent, but it no longer does.