# Is there a way (or tool) to update the iOS simulator in realtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

Does anyone know of a tool and/or process that allows changes to be made in Xcode and reflected realtime in the iOS simulator?

e.g. if I change the gradient color(s) in a button I can see them reflected as I finish typing?

I know [Spark Inspector](http://www.sparkinspector.com/) and/or [Reveal App](http://revealapp.com/) allow me to make changes to the simulator but as far as I know, not such complex changes as gradient colors, and it can't commit the changes to the source code. Conversely, [Pixate](http://www.pixate.com/) allows me to make the changes via css and update them in realtime, but I don't want to use css and a separate framework to do this.

Thanks a bunch for any help.
Kyle

Comment: You can set stuff from the debugger: [How to change variables value while debugging with LLDB in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9907387), and Xcode 3.something (maybe it was even Project Builder!) used to have this tied into the editor, but they've removed that functionality a long time ago. Mentioned here: [Hot code swapping in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10196155) -- "Fix and continue", it was called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hot Code Swapping in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196155/hot-code-swapping-in-xcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at [Injection For Xcode](http://injectionforxcode.com/).It is a Xcode plugin.After installing this plugin, you can modify source code, inject it into runtime, and see the change without restarting app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to look at this approach https://sherlock.inspiredcode.io.
It allows to change details of your application in real-time.